# How to correctly set background for retina?

Tags: ios, uiview

May be the question is elementary, but I have a bug with **setBackgroundColor**.

I have the `UIView` which contain `UITableView`. `UITableView` is clearColored. I'm trying to set background on `UIView`:

```
[self.viewForTable setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgIngrList.png"]]];
```

On normal iPad it's looks like:
[image]

But on retina iPad (like the second image began showing):
[image]

I have two images "bgIngrList.png" and "bgIngrList@2x.png" with **290x260** and **580x520**.

Where can be the bug?

**EDIT**

I have solved the problem by using `UIImageView` instead of `UIView`.

Thanks to everybody!!!

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me what's wrong with the second picture.  Is the background actually drawing too large, or is it just a larger screenshot from the retina simulator?  Are both `bgIngrList.png` and `bgIngrList@2x.png` in your project?

Comment: look at the bottom part of the second image, it looks like background draw image second time

Comment: I see it now… pretty weird.  I'm not sure what's going on but my first guess, just looking at the screenshot, would be that *another* view (with rounded corners) is drawing on top of the bottom region there.  You can log your whole view hierarchy with `[[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.  Maybe try that and see if anything suspicious shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

colorWithPatternImage: (as the name suggests) thinks your image as pattern to fill. so if the image you  give is smaller than the size of the view, its gonna draw the pattern image again rather than stretching it. that is what happening here. your image's size is smaller than view's size hence its drawing the image again at the bottom.  You can avoid this by adding a UIImageView and setting the image property rather than setting the backgroundColor of UIView.

Comment: Aha, this is the correct answer.  I wasn't paying enough attention to the size of the source images and was thinking that the source images were tiles for the greenish textured background, not images of the *whole* background.